# Why use the parameters if we can use variables?

Tags: javascript, parameters

Firstly, I'm a beginner, so don't be mad if what I'm saying is stupid.

So, this is the code that is using parameters:

```
function simpleExample (x) {

    document.write ("I love " + x);
}

simpleExample ("my mom.");
```

And this is the code that doesn't use the parameters:

```
function simpleExample () {

    var x = ("my mom");// Does not use the parameters

    document.write ("I love " + x);
}

simpleExample ();
```

So, the result is the same and... the global and local thing is also the same [both is local right?] So what does the difference?

Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: What if you want to print "I love my mom" and then "I love my dad"?

Comment: parameters basically are there to give a flexible input as variable instead of hardcoded.

Comment: Uhm… `simpleExample` #1 can print any sentence you want. `simpleExample` #2 can only print "I love my mom"… There is no *"variable"* in that second function.

Comment: Also think about the case when user writes in the input whom s/he loves and you output that calling your function with user input

Comment: You use parameter to manipulate the variable value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe right if you just want to say you're loving your mom. But, what if you also want to say other persons that you love? You write all that hard code everytime?

the answer is : no.

You just call that function with a parameter. And that's it. Nothing more.

```
simpleExample("my mom");
simpleExample("my dad");
simpleExample("justin bieber");  //we all hope you don't.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why use the parameters if we can use variables?

The point is that often we cannot use static (global) or constant variables. Consider your first function:

```
simpleExample("my mom.");
simpleExample("my dad.");
```

We are calling the same function multiple times with different arguments. This requires *parametrisation* of the code in the function that is otherwise the same for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using a parameter for a function allows the result of the function (be it a process or a result value) to differ based on an input that is not fixed at the time of writing the function.

Even with your simple example it should be obvious that the `simpleExample(x)` function with a parameter can be easily reused like so:

```
simpleExample('my mom');
simpleExample('and my dad too!');
simpleExample('my sister not so much');
```

This wouldn't be as easy with the variable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters is the essence of functions.

In the second case, the variable x is local to the scope of the fonction and will never change. That is, the execution of your function `simpleExample` will always have the same effect (logging "I love my mom" in the console).

The use of parameters allows your function to have an effect dependent to the input. In this case, the person you love can be changed depending of the parameter `x`.